# How to connect React front-end to NodeJS back-end API

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs, express

Please, I have a nodejs products API, which displays list of products for sale, and the price. It's working well with Postman. Now, I want to connect it to my react front-end. My nodejs server runs on port http://localhost:8001, while my react server is running on port http://localhost:3000. In my react's package.json file, I added "proxy": "http://localhost:8001/" just below the scripts object.
But when I do a fetch from my react front-end, I get the error "SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data". I have tried to log my result to the console, but nothing shows up.
Below are my codes.

App.js file in react

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      response: "" 
    }
  }

   callAPI() {
    fetch('/products')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then((result) => {        
        this.setState({ response: result })
      },
      (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callAPI();
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <>
        <h1>{this.state.response}</h1>
      </>
    )
  }
}
```

My package.json file in react

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.6",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.2.2",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8001/",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

My app.js file in node.js

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
app.use(cors());

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


// For people to access your API from other hosts
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization'
  );
  if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'PUT, POST, PATCH, DELETE');
    return res.status(200).json({});
  }
  next();
})

app.get('/products', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send({ "express": "Hello from express" });
});

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const error = new Error('Not found');
  error.status = 404;
  next(error);
})

app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.json({
    error: {
      message: error.message
    }
  })
})


module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the last slash from proxy settings:

`"proxy": "http://localhost:8001"`

It should help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you are right - slash doesn't matter. Finally I tried to run your code and all is ok but one thing:

In App.js file the render method should be changed to:

```
render() {
    return(
      <>
        <h1>{JSON.stringify(this.state.response)}</h1>
      </>
    )
  }
```

It is only modify I did. The rest of code seems to be ok and works fine.
Here is a proof: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZzUY.png) and here is the [link](https://gofile.io/d/Qu2iai) to download my code